# C#: string concatenation not working

Tags: c#, string, concatenation

Today I came across a problem I had never had before. I'm trying to check if a file exists from a value in Windows registry. To be more specific, I'm getting the installation path from Flight Simulator and checking if there is a module installed.

I get the registry key just fine and it is converted to a string (from an object) but I don't seem to be able to concatenate the filename after it (before is just fine).

```
RegistryKey pRegKey = Registry.CurrentUser;
pRegKey = pRegKey.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Microsoft Games\Flight Simulator\10.0");
string fSPath = pRegKey.GetValue("AppPath").ToString(); // Receives "S:/Apps/FSX/"
```

If I show a messagebox like this it does not concatenate:

```
MessageBox.Show(fSPath + "Modules");
```

Comment: For the record, I tried using StringBuilder and also explicitly converting both text portions.

Comment: The missing part is "what do you get instead". It does not concatenate, but what does it do? What's displayed in a message box?

Comment: Is there an exception or is the string result just "Modules"

Comment: Are you sure you are getting `fSPath` value correctly ? Did you debug your code line by line.

Comment: Is your control come across `MessageBox`, if so what you are getting..?

Comment: my guess is, that there is a '\0' character at the end of pRegKey.

Comment: @CSharpie - So? C#/.NET strings are not C strings (no null terminator).

Comment: If I write: MessageBox.Show(fSPath); or MessageBox.Show(fSPath + "Modules"); it shows just "S:/Apps/FSX/". If I write MessageBox.Show("test" + fSPath); it shows "testS:/Apps/FSX/". I'm guessing there is something to do with the slashes, but I already tried replacing them and nothing fixed.

Comment: @Oded that is not correct, just check yourself:             MessageBox.Show("HELLO \0 World");

Comment: @CSharpie - I think _you_ should test that. I am getting a `□` for `\0`.

Comment: @CSharpie may well be on the right track but with the wrong character? Is there a CRLF on the end of fsPath? Have you looked at fsPath as a char array to confirm there is no random whitespace characters on the end?

Comment: @Oded i did to be sure and it only tells me "Hello"

Comment: @CSharpie - That's more of an issue with how `MessageBox` displays things than strings in .NET

Comment: @Oded yeah well he was complaining that messagebox didnt showthe correct results for him. Guess there is an issue with \0 then as it seem to yield different results.

Comment: An fSPath.Length echoes 12, which would be correct for S:\Apps\FSX\

Comment: It sure is, since \0 is end of string and will not be counted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following line:

```
string fSPath = fsPath.Replace("\0","");
```

before using messagebox.

Comment: That did it! Wow, thanks! How come this \0 is there but does not show?

Comment: RegistryKey is a quite old class. I dont know which language it was written probably c or c++. Those languages use the \0 to tell where the end of the string is. And since it marks the end it is not displayed.

Comment: May want to use the Registry class instead.

Comment: the same happens to Registry. I need to remove the \0 too.

Answer (score 3):

Try other overloaded methods of [`GetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b7w04dz.aspx):

```
GetValue Method (String, Object)
GetValue Method (String, Object, RegistryValueOptions)
```

and use [`RegistryKey.GetValueKind`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey.getvaluekind.aspx) method to get registry data type of the value associated with the specified name.

we have [three registry data types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registryvaluekind.aspx) for string:

> ***`String`*** A null-terminated string.This value is equivalent to the `Win32 API` registry data type `REG_SZ`.
>
> ***`ExpandString`*** A null-terminated string that contains unexpanded references to environment variables, such as `%PATH%`, that are expanded when the value is retrieved. This value is equivalent to the `Win32 API` registry data type `REG_EXPAND_SZ`.
>
> ***`MultiString`***    An array of null-terminated strings, terminated by two null characters. This value is equivalent to the `Win32 API` registry data type `REG_MULTI_SZ`.